# How to set the default line terminator for new files in emacs?

Tags: emacs, newline, linefeed

Is there a something I can put in my .emacs config file to set the default line-ending style for newly created files?

I'm using GNU emacs for windows, but would like newly created files to use unix-style (line-feed only) line endings by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the following in my Windows section of my config:

```
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq eol-mnemonic-dos "(DOS)")
(setq eol-mnemonic-unix "\\")
```

Comment: Thanks - (setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix) was what I was looking for.